# mockwebserver not intercepting openConnection

Tags: android

Maybe I'm doing this wrong, but I am not using a library for company reasons to make a simple POST to a server. So right now I basically do:

```
fun post(payload: String, url: String) {
with(URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection) {
    requestMethod = "POST"

    doOutput = true
    val wr = OutputStreamWriter(getOutputStream())
    wr.write(data)
    wr.flush()
}
}
```

And then when I try to test it, I've tried various forms of

```
    @get:Rule
    var mockWebServer: MockWebServer = MockWebServer()

fun testPost() {
mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200))

        val url = "https://someinvaliddomain.com/person"
        mockWebServer.url("https://someinvaliddomain.com/person") // i've also just tried "/"

        api.post("hello", url)
}
```

But it seems like I don't have something set up correctly because the exception I get is "java.net.UnknownHostException." Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code, seems like it needs more information.
Make sure your API Request is working.
Make some corrections on

```
mockWebServer.url("/")
```

but on the other hand, you are trying to reach /person, so it should be

```
mockWebServer.url("/person")
```

For complete reference,please check https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

It gives a good overview for MockWebServer